# How to get all files from Gallery without using s3eImagePicker in Marmalade?

Tags: ios, marmalade

I have requirement to get all files from Gallery and show thumbnail of actual image file in Grid Layout for selection. In this case I cannot use s3eImagePicker as it opens Gallery application in which I cannot add my button. Basically my application requirement is show all images in Gallery to user in thumbnail form. When user select any thumbnail and press UpLoad button I need to copy actual image from Gallery to application folder selected by user. So my UI contains Grid Layout for thumbnail,List of Target Folders and two buttons i.e Cancel and Upload. This kind of UI is not possible with s3eImagePicket. So I am searching for other solution which can give path info of all files in Gallery.

Please note that I am developing application for iPad and Android.

Marmalade Team Member: Can you pls reply on this? For Contact I can read from device without using Default Contact application, but it is not possible for Gallery. Can you please raise this as new feature if posisble and if there is no solution exist for this?

Answer (score 0):

In marmalade if you are searching for the path of all files in a directory (e.g. a gallery directory), here is one way to get that:

```
std::string strDirectory = "[GALLERY PATH HERE]";
s3eFileList *pFileList = s3eFileListDirectory( strDirectory.c_str() );
if( pFileList == NULL )
{
    return;
}
char pFileName[255];
int32 iFileNameLen( 255 );
while( s3eFileListNext( pFileList,
                        pFileName,
                        iFileNameLen ) == S3E_RESULT_SUCCESS )
{
    s3eDeviceYield(); // use this yield if there are potentially many files

    std::string strImagePath = strDirectory + pFileName;

    ...
    do whatever you want now with your paths for files in gallery
    ...
}


s3eFileListClose( pFileList );
```